# Pythonic way to find hierarchy in a given list of accounts

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a MySQL Column with the following information:

```
codes = [
    "[1]",
    "[1-1]",
    "[1-1-01]",
    "[1-1-01-01]",
    "[1-1-01-02]",
    "[1-1-01-03]",
    "[1-1-02]",
    "[1-1-02-01]",
    "[1-1-02-02]"
    "[1-2]",
    "[1-2-01]",
    "[1-2-01-01]",
    "[2]",
    "[2-1]",
    "[2-1-01-01]",
    "[2-1-01-02]"
]
```

This is a hierarchical structure for accounts, and I need to know, for each account, which is parent and which is the child to add to a secondary table called `AccountsTree`.

My models are:

```
Accounts:
    id = db.Column(Integer)
    account = db.Column(Integer)
    ...
    numbers = db.Column(Integer)

AccountsTree:
    id = db.Column(Integer)
    parent = db.Column(Integer, db.ForeignKey('Accounts.id')
    child = db.Column(Integer, db.ForeignKey('Accounts.id')
```

I started coding something like:

```
For each_element in code_list:
    replace "[" and "]"
    split strings in '-' and
    make a new list of lists: each list element is a list of codes, each element of the inner list is a level
```

But that's starting not to look very good, and it looks as if I'm adding unnecessary complexity.

My workflow is:

```
(1) Import XLS from front end
(2) Parse XLS and add information to Accounts table
(3) Find out hierarchy of accounts and add information to AccountsTree table
```

I'm currently struggling with the 3rd step. So, after adding information to my Accounts table, how do I find out the hierarchical structure to fill my AccountsTree table?

My desired result is:

```
ParentID    |   ChildID
1           |   2
2           |   3
3           |   4
3           |   4
3           |   5
3           |   6
```

Anybody went through a similar challenge and can share a most efficient approach?
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide an example of the result you're looking to achieve?

Comment: I want to fill my second table, so it is something like ‘object [2] in the list is child of object[1]’. Next row would be: parent is object[2] and child is object[3], and so on.

Comment: Perhaps this tip will help: You don't need to split on every hyphen, only on the last one. A regex with a (default) greedy first group will accomplish that for you. Example code [here](https://pastebin.com/CJgPtfJJ).

Comment: @GordThompson this seems like a pretty clever solution, thanks a lot! I'm struggling to understand how the match works `r"\[(.*)-(.*)\]"`, it seems like it's scaping the special charachter `[` of the beginning, but not scaping the one from the end? And then it groups into the first part of the code (which would be the parent), and the second part (the child)? Would you mind posting an answer so I can mark it as accepted? Thanks mate!